# Any examples of running an smtp server with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, smtp

Has anyone seen any examples of how to run an smtp server with Rails hosted on heroku?

I'm interested to send mail to my own smtp server, manipulate the content with rails by adding a footer, adding link tracking etc, then send it out again.

Once I have the data, easy. Not sure where to begin in terms of setting up smtp.

Alternatively, are there any smtp services out there that will simply POST the data to my app?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SendGrid here http://sendgrid.com/

They've got some great APIs, and should be able to enable what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately they don't offer smtp parsing. Just inbound email parsing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want inbound email via a post to your application look at cloudmailin.com

Comment: I want to essentially intercept an smtp request and relay in through my app so I can modify the email. Parsing inbound doesn't do it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It's python, not RoR, but the Lamson project is pretty close to what you are talking about.

http://lamsonproject.org/

(Thanks Zed!)